# Alternative to Authorize.net CIM

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net

We need to store customer credit card and personal info. Id like to look at Authorize.net for CIM mgmt. but before I can go in that direction I wanted to see if anyone has expereince with others or preferences either in the business model or API's.

Comment: Sidenote; I have used authorize.net many times and like them.

Comment: Never tried any others, but, I researched this topic a little myself for a project and I am going with Authorize.NET's CIM.

Comment: LinkPoint is pretty much the second most popular gateway in my opinion next to auth.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorize.net is the go-to these days.

A new alternative I found is https://stripe.com/ they are free to start and charge 2.9% + 30¢ per transaction. Very developer friendly, see all their API Libraries: https://stripe.com/docs/libraries